# Cannot open URL link in emacs under msys

Tags: url

When trying to open URL link in emacs under MSYS2 I get the error *browse-url-default-windows-browser: Searching for program: No such file or directory, cygstart*.
Looking into the function `browse-url-default-windows-browser` I found out that it needed to call process `cygstart`:

```elisp
    (defun browse-url-default-windows-browser (url &optional _new-window)
      "Invoke the MS-Windows system's default Web browser.
    The optional NEW-WINDOW argument is not used."
    <...>
    ((eq system-type 'cygwin)
             (call-process "cygstart" nil nil nil url))
```

But there is no `cygstart` in MSYS2 according to its wiki [How does MSYS2 differ from Cygwin](https://github.com/msys2/msys2/wiki/How-does-MSYS2-differ-from-Cygwin). Though the variable `system-type` really equals `'cygwin` and cannot be changed to anything more appropriate.

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on @rucarden's solution I found you can use `browse-url-browser-function` to replace the original one inside your `.emacs`.
It's a documented setting in `browser.el`.

```
(when (eq system-type 'cygwin)
  (setq
   browse-url-browser-function
   (lambda (url &optional _new-window)
     (interactive (browse-url-interactive-arg "URL: "))
     (shell-command (concat "start " (shell-quote-argument url)())))))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that start works.   I made the following change to browse-url.el and then reloaded it with load-file.   There is probably a more elegant way of doing this that doesn't involve modifying browse-url.el.

```
((eq system-type 'cygwin)
 (shell-command (concat "start " (shell-quote-argument url)))))
```

Comment: Yes, it's better not to modify browse-url.el, because the edit will be gone after an update.